# Gazebo Planar Move Plugin for Omni-Directional Wheel

Tags: gazebo, plugin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I'm trying to simulate Kuka youbot with gazebo.
I have a question about gazebo planar move plugin.
Since kuka youbot has mecanum wheels, it needs to use gazebo planar move plugin.
So I followed [this instruction](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=ros_gzplugins) and added the plugin.

As a result, the mobile platform works fine, however the manipulator on the platform looks weird.
**Manipulator falls down because of gravity, but the motion is very slow.

And each joint requires more torques to move than without the plugin.**

Why planar move plugin affects robot motion in the above way ?
How can I avoid this situation ?

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/212889/gazebo-planar-move-plugin-for-omni-directional-wheel/) by [moyashi](https://answers.ros.org/users/2104/moyashi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 721 on 2015-07-04

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nlyubova](https://answers.ros.org/users/28191/nlyubova/) on 2016-10-09**:
hello,
I get exactly the same problem with Pepper when using libgazebo_ros_planar_move. The robot falls to one side when moving. Did you find a solution to your problem?

However, gazebo_ros_force_based_move gives the segfault. what can be a problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You could also try the [gazebo_ros_force_based_move](https://github.com/tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg/hector_gazebo/blob/indigo-devel/hector_gazebo_plugins/src/gazebo_ros_force_based_move.cpp#L174) plugin. It is similar to the planar move plugin, but applies forces and torques to the body of the robot, not bypassing the physics engine. I previously observed issues with the planar move plugin and a manipulator arm mounted on a robot (arm wobbling  around the z-axis when robot rotates). This doesn't happen with the force-based plugin. [Here's a example video](https://youtu.be/dHWFviA2S3E) of using it for a simulated tracked robot.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2015-11-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0